# PHP - Update each row in MySQL table from a web form

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I populate a web form with rows of data. Some of the fields I need to be updatable so I put the value into a text field. MySQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE EventID = %s AND CompNo = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsResults, "int"),GetSQLValueString($colname2_rsResults, "int"));
```

EventID and CompNo are passed in the URL.

Let's say the result is 50 rows. I want to be able to update the Name field (eg, make correction to the spelling), click a button and have the code update the database with any new values. It doesn't matter that most of the values will not change as this is a very infrequent operation.

I used to be able to do this in ASP but I can't seem to do in PHP.

This is the code I am using and I think it is completely wrong!!

```
if ((isset($_POST["JM_update"])) && ($_POST["JM_update"] == "form1")) { 

    $i = 0;
    $j = $totalRows_rsResults;

    while($i < $j)

    $resultID=$_GET['ResultID'];
    $vDelete=$_GET['Del'];
    if ($vDelete == 1) { 
    $delSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM Results WHERE ResultID=$resultID");
    mysql_query($delSQL,$connFeisResults);
    } else {
    $name=$_GET['Name'];
    $qual=$_GET['Qual'];
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE results SET Name = ".$name{$i}.", Qual = ".$qual[$i]." WHERE ResultID=$resultID");
    mysql_query($updateSQL, $connFeisResults);  

    $i++;

    }
    }
```

There is also a checkbox at the end of each row to check if I need that record deleted. That doesn't work either!!

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 and trying to adapt the update behaviours etc.

Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The statements in your `while` loop aren't surrounded by the appropriate syntax, you're missing the braces - `{}` - or a `:` and `endwhile;`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an opening brace after your while statement.

--UPDATED

Also, check your sprintf statements -- they look wrong, and they look like they're writing the raw '$resultID' to the SQL String, instead of the value within it.

See how to do it here: http://www.talkphp.com/general/1062-securing-your-mysql-queries-sprintf.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I have added the braces after the while and at the end of the $i++. Not getting any further...

Comment: I updated the answer to ask you to check your sprint statement...let me know if that helps.